# Restrict outlook calendar items to date range with AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to filter ([restrict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict)) Outlook calendar items to a specific date (today). I am very close, but I'm failing to correctly use the `Items.Restrict("[Start] >= xxxx AND [End] <= xxxx")`

I know you can call this from VBA, I have successfully filtered it using that in the past. So far what I have is below, I have hard-coded today's date while I'm testing. But this will be swapped out for a variable.

```
Outlook := ComObjCreate("Outlook.Application")
Namespace := Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Namespace.Logon("Outlook")
Calendar := Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar := 9)
oItems := Calendar.Items
; Calendar.Items.IncludeRecurrences := "True"
ItemCount := Calendar.Items.Count
oItemsInDateRange := oItems.Restrict("[Start] >= '10/18/2023 12:01 PM' AND [End] <= '10/18/2023 01:00 PM'").GetLast() ;strRestriction
item2 := oItemsInDateRange.Subject
msgbox % ItemCount " | " item2 " | " oItemsInDateRange.start
```

msgbox prints the 1174 calendar items found `|` the last meeting `|` and the start time of the last meeting. However, notice that I have the time frame filtered to a tight time frame today but its pulling back an Oct 12th meeting. How could that be?
[image: Msgbox return]